# comparing words in js with very strange result

Tags: javascript, unicode, comparison, persian

I have a persian word that I copied one from a text and write down the other one in my keyboard:

```
a = 'ﺧﻮاب'
"ﺧﻮاب"

b='خواب'
"خواب"

//lets compare 
a==b
false
```

Can someone explain me why? (you can test yourself!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their first 2 letters are different characters.

```
var a = 'ﺧﻮاب';
var b = 'خواب';

for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
    console.log(a.charCodeAt(i));
}
for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ){
    console.log(b.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

> **a** is `[65191, 65262, 1575, 1576]`
>
> **b** is `[1582, 1608, 1575, 1576]`

Now if I try this code:

```
var a = 'ﺧﻮاب';
var b = a; // Or you can copy and paste `a` value here.
a == b; // This will return `true`
```

Answer (score 2):

The first two characters are different, you can see the difference by running a.split('') and b.split('') in your browser's console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to find out differences like this is to paste it into a text editor.

You can see that the characters result in something different:

[image]

Comment: What is your text editor? I tried everything but look same

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at it with a hex editor and see that they have different hex codes. You'll notice that the first two characters are different between the strings.

The first string is:
[FEA7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=FEA7&preview=entity) [FEEE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=FEEE&preview=entity) [0627](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=0627&preview=entity) [0628](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=0628&preview=entity)

And the second:
[062E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=062E&preview=entity) [0648](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=0648&preview=entity) [0627](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=0627&preview=entity) [0628](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=0628&preview=entity)

[Free hex editor for mac.](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)

[Free hex editor for pc.](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

Answer (score 1):

The first two characters of each sequence are different:

- `a`: U+FEA7 U+FEEE ...
- `b`: U+062E U+0648 ...

The reason why they look the same is that `a` uses "presentation form" versions of the characters in `b`, which are used to mark the joining group of the character (e.g. initial, medial or final). In this case, `ARABIC LETTER KHAH INITIAL FORM` and `ARABIC LETTER WAW FINAL FORM`. These will have the same visual appearance as the characters in `b` once shaped by a font renderer (`ARABIC LETTER KHAH` and `ARABIC LETTER WAW`).

These presentation form characters in `a` only exist in Unicode for backwards compatibility (Unicode uses a different mechanism to encode the joining group now), and are canonically equivalent to those in `b`. The characters in `a` will be normalised into the characters in `b` under Normalisation Form C.